# react native expandable listview

Tags: react-native

I want to use "react-native-expandable-listview" this library with dynamic data also wants a custom UI for item and subcategory items.

Want customization when data coming from server-side

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the expandable list view where you can display dynamic data and also you can customise it according to your requirement

official url :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-expandable-listview

Comment: I use this library but how can I manage dynamic data in this, In that case when data come from server side

Comment: okay ! have you ever use flatlets? it's the same you have to pass your array list inside data keyword for parent and child the example have given in this 
url:     https://github.com/Cnilton/react-native-expandable-list-view

Comment: actually, the data array is different and also I want to set data dynamic which comes from API with a custom view for parent and child view.
Thank you